# How to make a rigid body object you're carrying not go through walls?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, rigid-bodies

I have a player who can carry objects with its gun in a "2.5D Platform Shooter" game but the problem I'm  experiencing at the moment is that every time I make the player hold the object(it has a rigid body) and pressed against the wall, the object goes through the wall. Please help unity fans.

This the code I'm using below to carry the object.

```
#pragma strict

var catchRange = 30.0;
var holdDistance = 4.0;
var minForce = 1000;
var maxForce = 10000;
var forceChargePerSec = 3000;
var layerMask : LayerMask = -1;       

@HideInInspector
var anim : Animator;

enum GravityGunState { Free, Catch, Occupied, Charge, Release};
private var gravityGunState : GravityGunState = 0;
private var rigid : Rigidbody = null;
private var currentForce = minForce;

function FixedUpdate() 
{
if(gravityGunState == GravityGunState.Free) 
{
if(Input.GetButton("Fire1")) 
{   anim.SetBool("Shoot", true);
var hit : RaycastHit;
if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, hit, catchRange, layerMask)) 
{
if(hit.rigidbody) 
{ 
rigid = hit.rigidbody;
gravityGunState = GravityGunState.Catch;

}
}
}else if(!hit.rigidbody){anim.SetBool("Shoot", false);}
}

else if(gravityGunState == GravityGunState.Catch) 
{    
rigid.useGravity = false;
rigid.MovePosition(transform.position + transform.forward * holdDistance);
if(!Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
gravityGunState = GravityGunState.Occupied;
}

else if(gravityGunState == GravityGunState.Occupied) 
{

if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, hit, catchRange, layerMask)){
Debug.DrawLine (transform.position, hit.point, Color.red);
}    
rigid.MovePosition(transform.position + transform.forward * holdDistance);
if(Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
gravityGunState = GravityGunState.Charge;
}

else if(gravityGunState == GravityGunState.Charge) 
{
rigid.MovePosition(transform.position + transform.forward * holdDistance);
if(currentForce < maxForce) 
{
currentForce += forceChargePerSec * Time.deltaTime;
}

else 
{       
currentForce = maxForce;
}

if(!Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
gravityGunState = GravityGunState.Release; 
rigid.useGravity = true; 
}

else if(gravityGunState == GravityGunState.Release) 
{   
rigid.AddForce(transform.forward * currentForce);
currentForce = minForce;
gravityGunState = GravityGunState.Free;
}

}

@script ExecuteInEditMode()
```

Comment: Sounds like the object doesn't have a collider.

Comment: It has a collider, not set to trigger, has rigidbody, and is not kinematic but still geoes through :(

Answer (score 1):

adding **collider** to **gameObjects** will prevent object from moving through each other and if it already has a collider and it is passing through check your settings as follows
Rigidbody  **Is Kinamatic** : False, **Is Triggger**:false
set the **Collision Detection** of rigidbody to **Continuous** or **Continuous Dynamic**
sometimes for **fast moving game objects** the collision wont be detected in these sceneraios you can use **Raycasting** for collisin detection here is DontGoThrough Script that use raycasting for collision detection

```
      using UnityEngine;    
      using System.Collections;

        public class DontGoThroughThings : MonoBehaviour        
        {

            public LayerMask layerMask; //make sure we aren't in this layer

            public float skinWidth = 0.1f; //probably doesn't need to be changed

            private float minimumExtent;

            private float partialExtent;

            private float sqrMinimumExtent;

            private Vector3 previousPosition;

            private Rigidbody myRigidbody;

            //initialize values

            void Awake()

            {

               myRigidbody = rigidbody;

               previousPosition = myRigidbody.position;

               minimumExtent = Mathf.Min(Mathf.Min(collider.bounds.extents.x, collider.bounds.extents.y), collider.bounds.extents.z);

               partialExtent = minimumExtent * (1.0f - skinWidth);

               sqrMinimumExtent = minimumExtent * minimumExtent;

            }

            void FixedUpdate()

            {

               //have we moved more than our minimum extent?

               Vector3 movementThisStep = myRigidbody.position - previousPosition;

               float movementSqrMagnitude = movementThisStep.sqrMagnitude;   

               if (movementSqrMagnitude > sqrMinimumExtent)

                {

                  float movementMagnitude = Mathf.Sqrt(movementSqrMagnitude);

                  RaycastHit hitInfo;



                  //check for obstructions we might have missed

                  if (Physics.Raycast(previousPosition, movementThisStep, out hitInfo, movementMagnitude, layerMask.value))

                     myRigidbody.position = hitInfo.point - (movementThisStep/movementMagnitude)*partialExtent;

               }      

               previousPosition = myRigidbody.position;

            }

        }
```

Comment: It has a collider, not set to trigger, has rigidbody, and is not kinematic and also set to continuous or continuous dynamic  but still goes through :(

Was I suppose to put that on my object that I'm gonna lift?

Comment: both objects has collider

Comment: I would like to send you a picture of what it looks like but it says I need more reputation :(

Comment: 2 Colliders where one has a rigidbody attached will cause a Collision

Comment: So I also have to put a collider on my wall that'll block the object that's being lifted and pressed against? and the one that's gonna be lifted has to have a collider and rigidbody?

Comment: here's a link from a different website that has a picture of my problem that might help make sense.

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/821891/how-make-a-rigid-body-object-your-carrying-to-not.html

Comment: you say one object goes through another object so there are two objects so if  one of them got a rigid body and collider and the other one just got a collider so they will collide that is it